# relay causing problem to controller

Tags: relay, high-voltage, computers

I have a relay which is electronically controlled by a computer (Odroid) and used as a switch for a high power circuit. The computer and the other circuit are powered with different plugs on the same multiple socket. When the relay opens the circuit, there are some issues with the computer (for example, some USB devices are not recognized anymore). Can this problem be related to the socket? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Probably not the socket no.

Comment: EMI from the relay contacts arcing is likely mucking up your computer (an SBC in this case). This is part of the reason why PLCs are so expensive.

Comment: can I avoid arcing in some way?

Comment: By avoiding the relay. Using an SSR rather than a mechanical relay (assuming that's what you have) should help.